# 2 order increment id generated after place order using paypal magento

Tags: magento, paypal

I am using magento 1.7.0.2

I have one order regarding issue with back end, i am using Paypal express checkout payment method for merchant country Australia.

After placing an order using Paypal express method, it shows the same order twice with different increment ids in order grid. Please see attached screen shot below

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to magento log file, payment_paypal_express.log

can you check if the same order info was submitted twice?

Comment: hi leo thanks for supports. i checked log file, there are one entry in [url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    [SetExpressCheckout] => Array
        () and another one is 
 [GetExpressCheckoutDetails] => Array
        () Array . so total two time user's email address even AMT reflected